# Knockout select options binding with array

Tags: javascript, jquery, knockout.js

I am trying to bind a select options with values from my array without success. I have tried to change how i work with the array my changing to from an observable to observableArray but it wont take the values.

This is my current attempt.

```
<select name="status"
data-bind="options: statuses,
  optionsValue: 'key',
  optionsText: 'value',
  value: status "></select>
```

Knockout:

```
$statuses = {
 1: 'Open',
 2: 'Closed',
 3: 'On hold'
}

self.statuses = ko.observable($statuses);
self.status = ko.observable(null);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're passing a dictionary not an array.

It should be something like:

```
$statuses = [
    'Open',
    'Closed',
    'On hold'
]

self.statuses = ko.observableArray($statuses)
```

With the following HTML

```
<select name="status" data-bind="options: statuses, value: status"></select>
```

If you want the key to be the value change `$statuses` to be:

```
$statuses = [
    {key: 'Open', value: 1},
    {key: 'Closed', value: 2},
    {key: 'On hold', value: 3}
]
```

And keep the HTML binding as you have it with the `optionsValue` and `optionsText`.